# Invalid regular expression in HTML5 input pattern in email input

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex, html

I need to use this regular expression in a HTML input (Email Type), I used to create a regex here  to match what we wanted to validate http://regexr.com/3gib9

Regex

```
/^([A-Z|a-z|0-9](\.|_){0,1})+[A-Z|a-z|0-9]\@([A-Z|a-z|0-9])+((\.){0,1}[A-Z|a-z|0-9]){2}\.(com|net|org|co|org)+((\.[A-Z|a-z|0-9]{2,4})?)$/gm
```

Pattern

```
^([A-Z|a-z|0-9](\.|_){0,1})+[A-Z|a-z|0-9]\@([A-Z|a-z|0-9])+((\.){0,1}[A-Z|a-z|0-9]){2}\.(com|net|org|co|org)+((\.[A-Z|a-z|0-9]{2,4})?)$
```

Element with Pattern

```
<input type="email" pattern="^([A-Z|a-z|0-9](\.|_){0,1})+[A-Z|a-z|0-9]\@([A-Z|a-z|0-9])+((\.){0,1}[A-Z|a-z|0-9]){2}\.(com|net|org|co|org)+((\.[A-Z|a-z|0-9]{2,4})?)$" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email address" value="<%= session("user_email_addr") %>" required="required" title="Please input a valid email">
```

And now I am getting this error (Invalid Escape) when I input any email in the form

```
Pattern attribute value ^([A-Z|a-z|0-9](\.|_){0,1})+[A-Z|a-z|0-9]\@([A-Z|a-z|0-9])+((\.){0,1}[A-Z|a-z|0-9]){2}\.(com|net|org|co|org)+((\.[A-Z|a-z|0-9]{2,4})?)$ is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^([A-Z|a-z|0-9](\.|_){0,1})+[A-Z|a-z|0-9]\@([A-Z|a-z|0-9])+((\.){0,1}[A-Z|a-z|0-9]){2}\.(com|net|org|co|org)+((\.[A-Z|a-z|0-9]{2,4})?)$/: Invalid escape
```

How can I made this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove unnecessary escaping backslashes and wrong `|` inside character classs, and just redundant constructs:

```
pattern="([A-Za-z0-9][._]?)+[A-Za-z0-9]@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\.?[A-Za-z0-9]){2}\.(com?|net|org)+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]{2,4})?"
```

See a demo below:

```css
input:valid {
  color: green;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1"> 
 <input pattern="([A-Za-z0-9][._]?)+[A-Za-z0-9]@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\.?[A-Za-z0-9]){2}\.(com?|net|org)+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]{2,4})?" title="Wrong email!"/>
 <input type="Submit"/> 
</form>
```

**Details**

- `^...$` - the anchors are not necessary in HTML5 pattern since the regex is anchored by default (`^(?:` and `)$` are added to the pattern automatically when translated into a regex)
- `[A-Z|a-z|0-9]` - the `|` inside a character class is treated as a literal `|` symbol, not as an alternation operator
- `(\.|_){0,1}` - the single char alternation makes little sense when one can use a *character class*, `[._]` is a more natural construct here. Besides, `{0,1}` is more naturally written as `?` quantifier.
- `\@` - **the Culprit!** - this char does not have to be escaped, and *can't be escaped* in an ES6 regex pattern that has a `u` modifier (this is a regex that HTML5 pattern translates into, e.g. `pattern="[A-Z]"` will be translated into `/^(?:[A-Z])$/u` regex)
- `(com|net|org|co|org)` can be reduced to `(com?|net|org)`: `com?` matches `com` and `co` (thus, `co` alternative may be removed) and `org` is repeated twice.

There might be other enhancements here, but you can also just use

```
type="email"
```

HTML5 email validation attribute.